# IE renders wrong glyphicons

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, internet-explorer

I am building a Rails app that uses Bootstrap and its components. On one page I have a datepicker which used `glyphicon-chevron-left` and `glyphicon-chevron-right`.

However, when the site is oped on IE, surprisingly, there is a bug. Occasionally, IE renders wrong icons. The bug is really random and sometimes I struggle to reproduce it. You can see the error and the code in the picture below:

[Wrong glyphicon](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BjzoV.png)
Has any of you encountered that? I've tried googling the problem but haven't found a soution. What could be causing that issue?

Any help will be highly appreciated!

Comment: first go Tools>Internet Options>Advanced tab, check "Always record developer console messages.". Save changes... now when your open the f12 dev tool it will list any scripting errors, markup errors or blocked content errors (ActiveX filtering, tracking protection, xSS)... When debugging your web page scripts make sure you have selected "Break on all exceptions" from the Debug tab dropdown (looks like a stop sign)... Font file errors usually appear in the Networking tab of the dev tool...you must click the Start button (>) first before refreshing the page to record your request and responses.

Comment: @RobParsons thank you for your answer. It doesn't throw any errors and the font file seems to be loaded.

The fact that reproducing the bug is completely random makes me think that it might have something to do with caching. However, I tried setting

`config.static_cache_control = "public, max-age=31540000` and the problem pertains.